# Symfony2 Use PHP Class Constant in YAML Config?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I know this is probably not possible, but is there a clean way to use a PHP class constant within a YAML config/services/etc. file for Symfony2?

For example, if I have this:

```
namespace My\Bundle\DependencyInjection;

class MyClass
{
    const MY_CONST = 'cookies';
}
```

Is something like this possible (in a .yml file):

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Some\Class
        arguments:
            - %My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\MyClass::MY_CONST%
```

That'd go a long way in helping maintain consistency between the two.

Comment: Why don't you inject the class and then access the constant in your service or add it the value as parameter to your config and inject it in your Class as well as your service? Anyway, you might want to look at OpenSky's RuntimeConfigBundle <https://github.com/opensky/OpenSkyRuntimeConfigBundle> which allows you to dynamically inject parameters to your config. The documentation is a bit scarce, but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I don't want something like the settings to affect how I write code in that way (it leaves a bad taste in my mouth). I don't really want to inject them during run-time either, since then it can't take advantage of caching.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In versions before Symfony 3.2, injecting PHP-constants only works with XML:

```
<parameter key="my_service.my_const" type="constant">My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\MyClass::MY_CONST</parameter>
```

If you want to keep yor yml files, you could just import the xml-file into your services.yml. Mixing config styles might be a bit ugly, but as far as I know this is the only way to do it.

If this doesn't work for you, my comment to your question applies.

Comment: You can also use PHP instead of XML. Adding a PHP import file gives you a lot of flexibility, just remember Uncle Ben Parker and be responsible with this great power!

Comment: For reference within the cookbook see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#constants-as-parameters

Answer (score 22):

As of Symfony 3.2, it's also possible to use PHP constants in YAML files using a special `!php/const:` syntax:

```
parameters:
    bar: !php/const:PHP_INT_MAX
```

See the [Symfony blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-php-constants-in-yaml-files) for more details.

---

**Please note**: In Symfony 4 the syntax [was slightly changed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25534#issuecomment-352333648). You have to use a space instead of a double colon, for example:

```
parameters:
    bar: !php/const PHP_INT_MAX
```

Otherwise, you will get a FileLoaderLoadException with the message "Notice: Uninitialized string offset".

Comment: Thanks @d70rr3s :)

Comment: Also perhaps is not so obvious you can put class constants there, since almost every example use global space constants.

Answer (score 21):

For Symfony >=2.4 you can use [expression language](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language)

Example:

```
'@=constant("Symfony\\Bridge\\Monolog\\Logger::INFO")'
```

Comment: Have you had any success using expression language as a value for a property? For instance, when [defining an event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-listener) via service tag:

 `{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: '@constant("\\App\\Namespace\\Class::Constant")', method: someEvent }`. 

In my own attempts, the expression never seems to be evaluated. Thought I'd ask before throwing out a post!

Comment: Tripe slashes worked in my case eg "@=constant('\\\Symfony\\\Bridge\\\Monolog\\\Logger::INFO')", not single nor double did

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to insert argument as plain 'text' in config and inside class `__construct($constant1)` then request constant through variable by `constant($constant1)` function.

But I am not sure about global constants here, because they may not be  defined at time of using, but it shouldn't be a problem for class constants with whole namespace, because namespace locator is already defined at moment of calling the class.

Example config:

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Some\Class
    arguments:
        - 'My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\MyClass::MY_CONST'
```

and example class method:

```
public function __construct($arg1)
{
    $myRequiredConstantValue = constant($arg1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but only when using eval'd code, which is generally frowned upon.

Given a class constant Permission::ACCESS_NONE e.g. you could do something like this in the yaml file:

```
permission: ACCESS_NONE
```

and the following in the code where you parse the yaml:

`eval("return \The\Complete\Namespace\To\Permission::".$context['permission'].";");`

This is of course butt-ugly code but it does work.

Comment: Keep in mind that functions like `eval()` might be disabled in most production environments, due to the security issues it might cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
arguments:
      - key_1: "value_1"
        !php/const App\Example::CONSTANT_1: 'value_0'
```

[github issue: Using a PHP class constant for a key in a YAML hash](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36624)

Answer (score -6):

This should work

```
arguments:
 - <?php echo My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\MyClass::MY_CONST."\n" ?>
```

Comment: Did you? for your reference: [Yaml introduction](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/yaml/introduction.html#executing-php-inside-yaml-files), [Source code](https://github.com/symfony/Yaml/blob/master/Yaml.php#L106). It's even mentioned in a [Recent security release](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-22-and-2-1-7-released)

Comment: @jonhattan tell me if I am wrong but, by default, yaml doesn't evaluate php right?

Comment: The above would work in Symfony 1.4. I don't know about Sf2.1.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry for being that harsh then. But still, it seems quite unsafe and only usable in unconventional ways.

Comment: Yaml::parse() can evaluate php code in .yml files ([when enabled](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-symfony-2-0-22-and-2-1-7-released)). If you want to do this (and I'm sure there are commercial use-cases to do so) then you need to import a php config file (using 'imports:'). This lets you use yml for the majority of things but PHP for the bits you might need it for.

In the php you can access the container and do things like: `$container->setParameter('foo.bar', FOO_BAR);`, where FOO_BAR is a php constant or some other old-skool naughty thing that serious Symfonians would frown upon.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is tagged symfony**2**