# Using class constants in Symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a route defined with an annotation, like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/doSomething/{param}", name="route_name", defaults={"param"=1})
*/
```

Is it possible to use a class constant instead of this hardcoded '1', like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/doSomething/{param}", name="route_name", defaults={"param"=MyBundle:MyEntity:DEFAULT_TYPE})
*/
```

(of course the above fails)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713913/symfony2-use-php-class-constant-in-yaml-config Although, they talk about `YAML` instead of annotation the conclusion is that only `XML` supports constant injecting

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can use constants in annotations, just use the FQN of the class:

```
/**
 * @Route("/doSomething/{param}", name="route_name", defaults={"param"=Namespace\MyBundle\MyEntity::DEFAULT_TYPE})
*/
```

If you are in the same namespace, or you import the class holding the constant, you can shorten it:

```
use Namespace\MyBundle\MyEntity;

/**
 * @Route("/doSomething/{param}", name="route_name", defaults={"param"=MyEntity::DEFAULT_TYPE})
*/
```

Comment: Excuse me, I've got network problems and it done something wrong. I've upvoted your answer now! Thanks, nice advice, however, there is only one bad thing - you have to define FQN, actually... Anyway, this works 0K!

Comment: Well you could import the class in your PHP code to shorten it.

Comment: This works even with `name` parameter: `name="{MyEntity::ROUTE_NAME}"`. However, if you'll try to redirect it, `$this->redirectToRoute(MyEntity::ROUTE_NAME)`, symfony will throw an exception stating that such route does not exist. Strange.

Comment: @DamagedOrganic your solution is not really "working" though. You're putting the constant as a literal string. Inserting the constant without quotes like so `name=MyEntity::ROUTE_NAME` will actually work